# Get named ranges in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Using PHPExcel, I would like to loop through all the named ranges in a workbook and then create a new tab for each one.

I am currently doing this in excel with a macro, like so:

```
Dim sheetName As String
sheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

Dim nName As Name

For Each nName In Names
    If InStr(1, nName.RefersTo, sheetName) > 0 Then
        Application.Goto Reference:=nName.Name
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = nName.Name
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
Next nName
mystring = Sheets(1).Name
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="P:\DP\CWBI\" & mystring & "_parsed.xls"
```

I can loop through active sheets in PHPExcel and dump them into an array for processing, like this:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$sheets = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($file);

print_r ($sheets);
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to loop through all the named ranges?

Edit:

I'm trying the first suggestion below, but not getting any output. Here's the code:

```
$file="span_test.xlsx";
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);

foreach($objPHPExcel->getNamedRanges() as $name => $namedRange) {
   echo $namedRange . "</br>";   
}
```

Got it working now, my mistake in trying to echo an object. should be

```
print_r($name)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to actually load the workbook to access the named ranges

```
foreach($objPHPExcel->getNamedRanges() as $name => $namedRange) { ... }
```

which returns a PHPExcel_NamedRange object for each named range

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but I"m not getting any output. See above. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: $namedRange will be a PHPExcel_NamedRange object, not a scalar value like a string. `echo "'", $namedRange->getWorksheet(), "'!", $namedRange->getRange();`